# Is it possible to select a branch just before the build in TeamCity?

Tags: git, teamcity, gated-checkin

TFS allows me to specify a branch against which build is run.

TeamCity's build configuration has `default branch` and `branch specification` parameters which are statically defined.

But I want to manually start the same build for different feature branches.

For example I have a `gated-checkin` build configuration which monitors only PRs, but sometimes I want to run this build for my not yet merged branches.

Comment: If you configure a project or build configuration to allow multiple branches you'll get a dropdown where you can pick which branch to build for.

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen Indeed! =) Thanks

Comment: @LasseV.Karlsen But wait, these are monitored branches. And I do not want all of the branches to be monitored.

Comment: This question seems ask how to do something in TeamCity, not related to TFS, suggest to remove TFS tag.